# How to use CollectionView inside View to not use the defaultContainer in Ember JS

Tags: ember.js

I want to insert CollectionView into View. It works but displays:

```
DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported. [defaultContainer#lookup]
```

How correctly insert CollectionView in View?

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("index", { path: "/" });
});

App.FirstView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'first'   
});

App.SecondView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'second'
});

App.MyCollection = Em.CollectionView.extend({
    content: ['f','s'],
    createChildView: function(viewClass, attrs){
        if (attrs.content == 'f') {
            viewClass = App.FirstView ;
        };
        if (attrs.content == 's') {
            viewClass = App.SecondView ;
        };
        return this._super(viewClass, attrs);
    }
});

App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
    myChildView: App.MyCollection.create()
});
```

templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
        {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{view view.myChildView}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="first">
     search
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="second">
    client
</script>
```

Sorry for my english, i am from Russia and understand it a little))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `IndexView` is directly instantiating the view. This style of instantiation is deprecated with nested views, so as to allow child views to get their parent `Container`.

Change that to declare the `myChildView` directly, and the deprecation warning will go away.

```
App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
    myChildView: App.MyCollection
});
```